# Use jQuery Dialog to dynamically show information based on a table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, angularjs

So I have an instant search table that uses AngularJS. On the far right side of the table, I had an ID column in a hyperlink format that takes the user to a specific page on the link that they select so that users can modify the data associated to the unique primary key.

Now I want to use jQuery to show the page in a dialog box. I've done this before but for some reason in the format that I'm wanting to apply it on it's not working.

**My PHP/AngularJS/HTML code:**

```
    <div>
       <table>
           <tbody>                 
            <tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit">
                <td>{{data.first_name}} {{data.last_name}}</td>
                <td>{{data.team_name}}</td>
                <td>{{data.role}}</td>
                <td>{{data.phone}}</td>
                <td>{{data.to_date}}</td>
                <td>{{data.email}}</td>
                <td><a id="modifyLink" href="admin/admin_edit.php?id={{data.id}}">{{data.id}}</a></td>   
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>        
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems == 0">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h4>No data found</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems > 0">    
        <div pagination="" page="currentPage" on-select-page="setPage(page)" boundary-links="true" total-items="filteredItems" items-per-page="entryLimit" class="pagination-small" previous-text="&laquo;" next-text="&raquo;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="modify" class="divider"></div>
```

**My AngularJS code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
         var dlg=$('#modify').dialog({
           title: 'Modify',
           resizable: true,
           autoOpen:false,
           modal: true,
           hide: 'fade',
           width:600,
           height:500
         });


         $('#modifyLink').click(function(e) {
           dlg.load('admin/admin_edit.php');
           e.preventDefault();
           dlg.dialog('open');
        }); 
});
```

So again, I want this page to pop up on a dialog box, and show all the contents of admin_edit.php in that same dialog box, what am I missing? How do I achieve this?

Comment: So what goes wrong exactly? Is XHR run successfully? Is dialog box empty or filled with gibberish? Any JS errors in a console?

Comment: @НЛО Nothing happens, when I click on the dynamic links it sends me to the static page and it doesn't utilise the jQuery Dialog script at all

Answer (score 0):

Couple things :

Don't use an id for the link (because you will have many links and it's not healthy that they all share the same id), use class instead.

Also `e.preventDefault();` must be the first statement on your click handler as it will prevent from navigating to a different page (you want to stay in the current page and display the dialog).

HTML/AngularJS

```
<div>
       <table>
           <tbody>                 
            <tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit">
                <td>{{data.first_name}} {{data.last_name}}</td>
                <td>{{data.team_name}}</td>
                <td>{{data.role}}</td>
                <td>{{data.phone}}</td>
                <td>{{data.to_date}}</td>
                <td>{{data.email}}</td>
                <td><a class="modifyLink" href="admin/admin_edit.php?id={{data.id}}">{{data.id}}</a></td>   
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>        
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems == 0">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h4>No data found</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="filteredItems > 0">    
        <div pagination="" page="currentPage" on-select-page="setPage(page)" boundary-links="true" total-items="filteredItems" items-per-page="entryLimit" class="pagination-small" previous-text="&laquo;" next-text="&raquo;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="modify" class="divider"></div>
```

jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
         var dlg=$('#modify').dialog({
           title: 'Modify',
           resizable: true,
           autoOpen:false,
           modal: true,
           hide: 'fade',
           width:600,
           height:500
         });


         $('.modifyLink').click(function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           dlg.load(this.href).dialog('open');
        }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for trying but it doesn't seem to work. Page `admin_edit.php` needs to load inside the dialog box.